# SourceKitService & swift Consumes 100% CPU and hundred Giga memory

Tags: swiftui

1.

```
Text(String(format: "%.1fs", manager.currentTime))
    .font(.caption).foregroundColor(.secondary)
```

2.

```
Text("\(manager.currentTime)")
    .font(.caption).foregroundColor(.secondary)
```

Code #1 will consumes 100% CPU and hundred Giga memory, but code #2 will works fine. how strange?

XCode 11.3

Comment: Doesn't happen for me... `manager.currentTime` is a float, right? Also, why the `s` in `"%.1fs"`?

Comment: @Published var currentTime: Double = 0 and s means second.

Comment: @Yonat I found this issue is nothing to do with the code, It just happens for nothing, and maybe disappear later.